# Merge 2 arrays and keep ONLY duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, merge, duplicates

So, i have 2 arrays which look like this:

```
$a = array(1,3,5);
$b = array(2,3,4,5);
```

The expected result should look like this:

```
array(3,5);
```

Is there a quick and easy way to achieve my expected result? :)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php ?

Comment: "Merge arrays" or "keep only duplicates"? That's a huge difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option One:

```
$a = array(1,3,5);
$b = array(2,3,4,5);
$result = array_intersect($a, $b);
print_r($result);
```

Option 1 output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
)
```

Option 2:

```
$a = array(1,3,5);
$b = array(2,3,4,5);
$resultTwo = [];
foreach($a as $val){
    if(in_array($val, $b)){
        $resultTwo[] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($resultTwo);
```

Option 2 Output (unlike option 1, the array index starts from 0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
)
```